# Proving that for $f:[0,1]\rightarrow R$, there exists $x_1, x_2$ such that $x_1\ne x_2$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=\lambda$

Tags: calculus

Let  $f:[0,1]\rightarrow R$, a continuous function such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Assume that there exists an M such that:
$$
\max \{ f(x) \mid x \in [0,1] \} = M > 0
$$
Prove that for every $ 0 \lt \lambda \lt M $ there exists $x_1,x_2 \in [0,1]$ that fulfill the following requirements:

1.) $x_1 \ne x_2$

2.) $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=\lambda $

I'm leaning towards picking $a,b \in [0,1]$ such that $ -1\lt a \lt b \lt1$. f is then also continuous in [a,b] because it is a subgroup of [-1,1]

Here I'm having difficulties figuring out where to continue with this train of thought (if it's even correct.), so I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: Your argument makes no sense at all to me: If $a, b \in [0, 1]$, then the bound $-1 < a$ is true but completely useless. In this case, $[a, b]$ is a sub*set* of $[-1, 1]$ but not a subgroup (and there's no group structure here...). And $f$ is not defined on $[-1, 1]$, but only on $[0, 1]$. So unfortunately, your train is missing both an engine and tracks....

Comment: As a hint in the correct direction, though: Intermediate value theorem applied twice.

Comment: Seems like it is possible to use Intermediate value theorem twice: we have two intervals, $[0,x_m]$ and $[x_m,1]$, where $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=0$, $x_m$ is one on the points where $f(x)=M$ (it is not $sup$, so this $x_m$ exists) and $f(1)=0$ again. So it takes any value in between $0$ and $M$ on both intervals.

Comment: @T.Bongers the reason I wanted to declare a,b was to try to use the IVT. Thanks for clearing up my confusion!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $a\in(0,1)$ such that $f(a)>\lambda$ and apply the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) on the intervals $[0,a]$ and $[a,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that a continuous function attains its maximum value in a closed interval. Thus there is a point $c \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(c) = M$ and since $M > 0$ it follows that $c \neq 0, c \neq 1$ and hence $c \in (0, 1)$.

Now you can apply IVT in $(0, c)$ and $(c, 1)$ and your job is done. I hope you can fill in the details.